# How to add ajax close listener to my panel dynamically?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I create my panel dynamically and I want to add ajax close listener dynamically too, but doesn't work for me. For each Panel:

```
    int u = _memosId.get(i);
    Panel panel = (Panel)_application.createComponent(_context, "org.primefaces.component.Panel", "org.primefaces.component.PanelRenderer");

    panel.setId("mymemo_" + String.valueOf(u));
    panel.setHeader(_userNames.get(i));
    panel.setClosable(true);
    panel.setToggleable(true);


    HtmlOutputText memo = new HtmlOutputText();
    memo.setValue(_userMemos.get(i));  
    panel.getChildren().add(memo);


    AjaxBehavior ajaxBehavior =(AjaxBehavior)_context.getApplication().createBehavior(AjaxBehavior.BEHAVIOR_ID);
    ajaxBehavior.addAjaxBehaviorListener(new ClosePanelListener());
    ajaxBehavior.setTransient(true);
    panel.addClientBehavior("close", ajaxBehavior);

    _column1.addWidget(panel.getId());
    getDashboard().getChildren().add(panel);
```

and my class listener:

```
    private static class ClosePanelListener implements AjaxBehaviorListener 
    {

        @Override
        public void processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException 
        {
         System.out.println("----------->>>>>>>>>>AjaxListener CALLED!!! "); 
        }
    }
```

The listener is not invoked.

Comment: Which version of primefaces are you using?

Comment: Ajax4jsf is a sublibrary of RichFaces (it are those `<a4j:xxx>` tags). You're not using that anywhere in your code. Instead, you're using PrimeFaces. Please do not tag the question with `[ajax4jsf]` then, thank you.

Comment: Also, do not whine "please help me, I'm stuck" at end of every post. It looks so stupid and unprofessional. [Just ask the question the smart way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). I edited your post accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your concrete problem is caused because the following line,

```
AjaxBehavior ajaxBehavior =(AjaxBehavior)_context.getApplication().createBehavior(AjaxBehavior.BEHAVIOR_ID);
```

essentially creates an `<f:ajax>`, while this `<p:panel>` close listener is really only supported by `<p:ajax>`. You can also see it in the generated HTML output; `Mojarra.ab()` (or whatever MyFaces specific function in case you're using MyFaces instead of Mojarra) is been used instead of `PrimeFaces.ab()`.

In order to properly create a `<p:ajax>`, you need to use PrimeFaces own `AjaxBehavior` instead and let your listener extend from PrimeFaces own `AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl`:

```
import org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehavior;
import org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl;
```

```java
AjaxBehavior ajaxBehavior = new AjaxBehavior();
```

```java
public static class ClosePanelListener extends AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl
```

*(note that I changed the nested class from `private` to `public`, otherwise you may end up in visibility troubles with some EL impls)*

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the variable naming convention `_application` and `_context` suggests that they are held as instance variables of the backing bean class. This is a very bad idea as to design and thread safety. They should be obtained in method local scope and never be assigned as instance variables.

Further, have you considered `<ui:repeat>` or `<c:forEach>` for the very purpose of dynamically creating panels in a loop? This will end up in much cleaner and declarative code than this mess.

Comment: Thank you, it works for me! I take a look for <ui:repeat> and <c:forEach>.

Answer (score 0):

Try using MethodExpression instead of directly creating your listener. ClosePanelListener should be a managed bean in this case.

```
 Application application = _context.getApplication();
 ExpressionFactory ef = _context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
 MethodExpression me = ef.createMethodExpression(_context.getELContext(),
     "#{closePanelListenerBean.processAjaxBehavior()}", null, new Class[]{AjaxBehaviorEvent.class});

 AjaxBehavior ajaxBehavior = new AjaxBehavior();
 AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl ajaxBehaviorImpl = new AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl(me, me);        
 ajaxBehavior.addAjaxBehaviorListener(ajaxBehaviorImpl);       
 panel.addClientBehavior("close", ajaxBehavior);
```

Comment: Thank you for responding quickly, but I already tried with MethodExpression and I get an error caused by "new AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl(me)". Apparently it comes from the constructor, it needs two arguments. May be you have a tip?

Comment: Check this topic in primefaces forum 'http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5344&hilit=ajaxbehavior', user dmantil posted a workaround for the problem (replay send '07 Dec 2010, 04:37') maybe it will help. Btw you didn't have to accept the answer if it didn't solve your problem.

Comment: I update my answer. Here is src for AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl, you can check how these two listeners from constructor are processed: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/behavior/ajax/AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java?spec=svn8893&r=8893